# Build a second step of a nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I try to build a nested form with two bearing (= post do push do reviews)
And I have this error :

[Error generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8pSr.png)

I would like to know if I have the good practices to succeed this creation ?

My code

Views/pushs/show:

```
<%= link_to 'Add comment', new_post_push_review_path(@push.post_id, @push) %>
```

Reviews/controller :

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :find_post
  before_action :find_push

  def new 
    @review = Review.new 
  end 

  def create
    @review = @post.push.reviews.create(review_params)
     @review.post_id = @push.post_id
    @review.push_id = @push.id 
    @review.user_id = current_user.id

    if @review.save 
      redirect_to push_path(@push.post_id, @push)
    else 
      render 'new'
    end 
  end 

  private 

  def review_params
    params.require(:review).permit(:rating, :comment)
  end 

  def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  end 

  def find_push
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @push = Push.find(params[:push_id])
  end 

end
```

Views/reviews/new:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@post, @post.push.reviews.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :rating %>
  <%= f.input :comment %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

& the routes :

```
resources :posts do 
  resources :pushs do 
    resources :reviews
  end 
end
```

Comment: shouldn't the push nested resource be named `pushes` ? The error is for an undefined method `push` for @post. How are they related ? post has_one push or has_many pushes ?

Comment: Normaly yes, but it's working like that from the beginning, so I continue like that.

Comment: Is post/push/user has_many :reviews.   And Review belongs_to :post/push/user

Comment: How are post and push related ?

Comment: I do not understand the question, you are talking about the routes or the models ?

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific. How are the post and push models related. If its has_one then post.push would work. If its has_many then it might not

Comment: Oh, Ok I understand what you want to say. Well a push is created from a post (with post_id and user_id) & the review is related to the push (with post_id / user_id and push_id). Do I have to include automaticly the post way if i'm in a nested form (of push) which is already a nested form (of post) ?

Comment: @AlokSwain I changed all has_many reviews => has_one review, but I still have the same errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114525/discussion-between-jean-zaniloi-and-alok-swain).